# Saving an Image file using binary Files - pyspark

Tags: python, image-processing, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I save Image file(JPG format) into my local system. I used BinaryFiles to load the pictures into spark, converted them into Array and processed them. Below is the code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math
images = sc.binaryFiles("path/car*") 
imagerdd = images.map(lambda (x,y): (x,(np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(y)))))
```

did some image processing and now key has path and value has Array for Image

```
imageOutuint = imagelapRDD.map(lambda (x,y): (x,(y.astype(np.uint8))))
imageOutIMG = imageOutuint.map(lambda (x,y): (x,(Image.fromarray(y))))
```

How can I save the Image to local/HDFS system, I see there is no option pertaining to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save data to local file system just collect as local iterator and use standard tools to save files records by records:

```
for x, img in imagerdd.toLocalIterator():
    path = ... # Some path .jpg (based on x?)
    img.save(path)
```

Just be sure to `cache` `imagerdd` to avoid recomputation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution zero323, what should I do if I am running it on HDFS?

Comment: You can for example analyze how [hibToJpeg](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/examples/hibToJpeg.html) handle this. But if you ask about pure PySpark I have no idea.